# Swapping all smallest and largest number in an array/vector

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I was trying to make a program that swaps all the biggest and smallest numbers in an array or a vector. I came up with a program but for some reason I'm not able to debug it to get the problem. Its not printing the vector, neither do I know what the issue is. Can anyone please help me.

[Desired Input and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfyZE.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n; //size input
    vector<int> arr;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) //filling up the vector
    {
        int input;
        cin>>input;
        arr.push_back(input);
    }
    vector<int> arr1=arr; //copying the vector
    sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end()); //sorting the new vector
    int i=0,j=n-1,i1=0,j1=n-1; //i and j are for the vector arr & i1 and j1 are for vector arr1
    while(i1<j1)
    {
        if(arr1[i1]==arr[i] && arr1[j1]==arr[j]) //if the first and last number of the sorted vector is found in arr the swap
        {
            int temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
            i1++;
            j1--;
            i=0; // i and j are set to initial value so that it is checked from the start
            j=n-1;;
        }
        else if(arr1[i1]<arr[i] && arr1[j1]==arr[j]) //if only the biggest place element is found the increase i 
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if(arr1[i1]==arr[i] && arr1[j1]>arr[j]) //if only the smallest place element is found the decrease j
        {
            j--;
        }
        else if(arr1[i1]!=arr[i] && arr1[j1]!=arr[j]) //if none of them are found then increase i and decrease j
        {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    for(int f=0;f<n;f++) //print the vector
        cout<<arr[f]<<" ";
    return 0;
}

/*
Sample input 1
6
12 34 87 56 38 98

Sample output 1
98 87 34 38 56 12

Sample input 2
6
8 7 9 2 4 6

Sample output 2
4 6 2 9 8 7

*/
```

Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It'd probably be much simpler if `arr1` contained the indexes of the items in `arr`

Comment: The description of the problem is not clear at all.  What do you mean by "swap all smallest and largest numbers"?

Comment: Include input and desired output as _text_, not as a linked image (nor as something at the bottom of the code). -1.

Comment: Try to output a newline at the end, after you print out the array.

Comment: Your program seems to work exactly the way you wanted it to be

Comment: @bipll Thanks that did work for some reason, and now even after removing the newline it works, but only for the sample output 2. I'm not able to get sample out 1 working. I want to know what is wrong in the program. That's causing this issue.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep The sample output 2 is working now. Don't know what was the issue but the Sample output 1 is not showing anything, its stuck in an infinite loop i guess, but i don't know where.

Comment: @Enrico Okay, thank you for mentioning, will take care about it next time. I'm actually new to stackoverflow so I don't know about the good practices.

Comment: @Roy0Anonymous that's what the help pages are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler method would be to make a vector of indexes rather than sorting the vector and trying to find the values in the original vector. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> arr;
    std::vector<int> indexes;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int input;
        std::cin >> input;
        arr.push_back(input);
        indexes.push_back(i);
    }
    std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&](int a, int b) {return arr[a] < arr[b]; });
    for (int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        std::swap(arr[indexes[i]], arr[indexes[j]]);
    }
    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[f] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, it did work but I didn't understand the part "[&](int a, int b) {return arr[a] < arr[b]; }" in the sort function. Specially [&](int a, int b). Can you please tell me about it.

Comment: its a [lamda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)